# RewriteRule for blog posts with a subdomain in the URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

working on a writing a redirect rule but I'm not too familiar with them or with the syntax.

Basically I have Wordpress URLs that look like this:

```
https://example.com/blog/blog-title/garbagetext
```

I need to be able to redirect URLs like this to our 404 page, and my first attempt was with:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.`*)/(.`*)/$ https://www.example.com/404.php [R=301,L]
```

This worked, but it also made it impossible to access actual blog posts, and is also redirecting URLs that look like this:

```
example.com/blog/blog-title
```

Any ideas how to make this work properly?

Comment: What do the URLs for your "actual blog posts" look like? The rule you posted shouldn't redirect a URL of the form: `example.com/blog/blog-title`. There may also be a conflict with existing directives - please post the entire `.htaccess` file, since the order of the directives is important. Why are there backticks in the regex and why does the regex end in a slash, when your example URL does not end in a slash? You also switch between non-www and www URLs - is this significant?

Comment: The actual blog posts look like this: https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/customer-reviews/

The posts that need to be redirected to the 404 are any posts that have text following that trailing slash, so far example:
https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/customer-reviews/asdfa

The rule I posted is redirecting both URLs to the 404, but I just need a rule that can redirect the latter. There are no prior rules in the .htaccess file, this is the first minus the WordPress standards. No, the switch between non-www was accidental (sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^blog/(.`*)/(.`*)/$ https://www.example.com/404.php [R=301,L]
> :  
> example.com/blog/blog-title
> ```

The directive you posted could not redirect the example URL that you say is being erroneously redirected. So, either you have other directives (possibly in other `.htaccess` files, or the server config) or there is a conflict with existing directives, or you are seeing a cached response? If you've previously experimented with 301 redirects then these will have been cached aggressively by the browser. (It can be easier to test with 302 - temporary - redirects for this reason.)

Since you are using WordPress (which uses a *front controller*) then any redirects should appear at the start of the file, *before* the front controller.

You also appear to have an erroneous slash at the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* that will fail to match an intended URL of the form `/blog/blog-title/garbagetext`.

I'll ignore the *backticks* for now - I assume they are probably just a styling typo in your question?

> I need to be able to redirect URLs like this to our 404 page

You shouldn't be *redirecting* to a 404 page. It should be served with an internal subrequest instead. If you *redirect* then you first send a 3xx response back to the client, the client then issues a second request for your `404.php` page (exposing the URL) and then you have to make sure you are manually setting the appropriate 404 HTTP response header.

So, you need to define the appropriate `ErrorDocument` and `R=404` the response.

> The posts that need to be redirected to the 404 are any posts that have text following that trailing slash, so far example: `example.com/blog/customer-reviews/asdfa`.

Try the following instead, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^blog/.+/. - [R=404]
```

This will match `/blog/customer-reviews/asdfa`, but it won't match `/blog/customer-reviews/` (or `/blog/customer-reviews`). The `R=404` flag triggers an internal request to the defined error document. The `L` flag is not required when using a none 3xx code. When there is no *substitution* text (ie. no target URL) then specify a hyphen (`-`) instead.

And make sure you've cleared your browser cache.